# MySQL format numbers with comma

Tags: mysql, number-formatting

How can I print the integer part of a number with commas separating every three digits?

For example,

```
 12345    -> 12,345
 1234.567 -> 1,234.567
```

Answer (score 21):

Use the [FORMAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format), which works for floating point numbers as well as for integers:

Floating point numbers:

```
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.123456, 4);
        -> '12,332.1235'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.1,4);
        -> '12,332.1000'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.2,0);
        -> '12,332'
```

Integers:

```
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12334, 0);
        -> 12,334
```